# Proving a property of the derivative $ Df(c)$ being surjective linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that the derivative $ Df(c)$ is surjective linear transformation. Prove that there exists $r > 0$ such that $ Df(x)$ is surjective for all $x \in B_{r}(c).$ Could anyone give me a hint please on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is $f$ a $C^1$ function?

Comment: it is not stated clearly in the question ..... but I think so @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: If $f\in C^1$, then $Df(x)$ is continuous in $x$. Note that a matrix $A$ is surjective if and only if $AA^T$ is invertible and that an invertible matrix remains invertible if you wobble it a little in whatever direction.

Comment: Is $f$ a function between finite-dimensional spaces or between infinite-dimensional spaces?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a $C^1$ function, that is $x\mapsto Df(x)$ is continuous, then
this reduces to linear algebra.

One has a surjection $Df(c)\in L=\text{Lin}(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m)$, so that $n\ge m$.
The set of surjections in $L$ is open, so for $x$ in a neighbourhood of $c$, $Df(x)$
is always continuous. To see the surjections are open in $L$, consider
their complement, the non-surjections. These are the matrices whose minors
of size $m$ all vanish. There minors are continuous functions of the matrix,
so their vanishing sets are closed.